# How can I restore the sort interface for Mail.app to the way it was before the Catalina upgrade?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I've been using Apple's Mail.app since 1993 and have grown quite accustomed to its "legacy" interface. One of the nice things about the interface is that it was a standard NSTableView and you could just click at the top of the column to sort it by date, sender subject, or what every you wished.

With Catalina, that's changed. Now there is a pull-down menu in the top-left corner that you can click to change the sort order. It's a different UI than every other table on the system.

I realize that some things change, but I wish that this was one of the things that stayed the same. Is there any way to change it back?